# Is there a way to obtain a static URL for videos hosted on openloadmovies.net?

Tags: javascript, php, jwplayer

Movies on https://openloadmovies.net can be downloaded by clicking on the download button in the JW Player window. However every mp4 file is assigned a URL which is refreshed every few hours.

Question: Is it possible to obtain a static URL for a JW Player movie found on openloadmovies.net?

I have looked at a page's source code (e.g. https://openloadmovies.net/movies/early-man-2018/), but am not experienced enough to determine if it is possible.

Comment: You should ask the site owners if this is possible.

Comment: Since it changes url every hours. *I think* static url probably not exist, otherwise the dynamic urls are meaningless.

Comment: it´s just a test, if somebody klicks this in later than one hour those urls are probably static http://51.158.78.182/videos/y7xjngdnh3net8y9o9j1ba31za.mp4 e.g how do you know about your statement with the refresh, i also wonder if this can actually work with video-ressources that are longer than one hour ...

Comment: @johnSmith The link you provided now says "video not found or has expired". I also tested my statement multiple times before making the claim on this forum.

Comment: @appleapple You may be right, the following javascript code is found in a sample movie page. The text in bold seems constant which may be how openloadmovies is calling the video in question, based on the load.php file: var Player = "https://openloadmovies.net/wp-content/plugins/apiplayer/load.php";
  LoadPlayer("jwplayer-1323729400","**bUxHK0orMnVHOEFyT0oxamMyeS9rVU9XMWtXc00zc1ZmQ1hxa25waU5QRVhCWXdnU1VjSjIrUUtlVWRCeUJvY21MMUluOHJhSFNQLzJPdExjSHRVN2VKNFJEM2ZvYThZWUY2L2FRYmc3bUc5amw2NnV5bGgxMzd1a2UxMzNHdTJiZGRhYk1lMjZTNytETUx2a2ZEam1kRDBWYU9JMWNnendnSTdQcWt4VFdFUjczVlB4bGNUN2src3FwcnMwRjFh**");

Comment: @JeroenHeier great idea, will update if I get a response.